# Unreliable ipNetToMediaPhysAddress SNMP entries in Brocade ICX 6450

Tags: c#, network-programming, snmp

I'm writing software that performs a minor form of network discovery by looking up LLDP neighbor switch IP addresses using SNMP.  I've had success finding neighbor switch information in lldpRemoteSystemsData (1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4), and then finding the corresponding switch IP address in iPNetToMediaPhysAddress (1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2).  I'm finding that some of our Brocade ICX6450 switches seem to be missing certain neighbor IP address entries in iPNetToMediaPhysAddress.

I can telnet to a switch and run

```
show lldp neighbor detail
```

and all the neighbor information I need is there, including the IP address I'm looking for.  It's obviously known to the switch, but missing when I query the switch using SNMP.  All switches involved have the same running config as one another.

Can I expect to reliably find neighbor switch IP's using iPNetToMediaPhysAddress, or is something wrong?

If there is a better undocumented way to find neighbor switch IP's, please let me know and I'll post a new question.

Comment: This is very specific to a vendor and its products, so your best resource should be the vendor itself. Stack Overflow is not for everything.

Comment: I don't think the question is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  Switch vendor aside, the bottom line of what I'm asking for is what one should see when querying iPNetToMediaPhysAddress.  Is the response not vendor-netural?  If someone can tell me that all switches, regardless of vendor, should reply with every neighbor IP for that SNMP query, then of course I'll go to the switch vendor for further help.  Perhaps it was a mistake to try to include the vendor name.

Comment: If this is your very first time to touch a standard, I can understand that you have no idea how a vendor can heavily control what is the output/response. Vendor neutral is just a saying unless the standard itself is strict enough, while old standards, such as HTTP/SNMP, are not. See how web browsers are not compatible with each other and you know SNMP cases would be even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found information that indicates the iPNetToMediaPhysAddress reply is based on the current state of the ARP cache on the switch.  I pinged the missing neighbor switch from the switch in question, and the IP address is now showing up in the iPNetToMediaPhysAddress reply.

https://community.brocade.com/t5/Ethernet-Switches-Routers/How-to-get-mac-address-via-SNMP/td-p/17055